# Cell in row equals a word then add 0s to every used cell below that

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Add_Leading_Zeros()

Dim LastColumn As Integer
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim HeaderRange As Range, HeaderCell As Range

Set HeaderRange = Range("A1:A" & LastColumn)

For Each HeaderCell In HeaderRange
    If InStr(1, HeaderCell.Value, "Title") > 0 Or InStr(1,   HeaderCell.Value, "title") > 0 Then
    Dim TitleRange As Range, TitleCell As Range
    Set TitleRange = 'range of that cell's used cells in that column

    'Add Zeroes to front of number until total numbers = 4

End Sub
```

Above is a rough outline of what I'm aiming for. I want to have my macro scan a row and if any cells in that row match a word then I want to add 0's to the front of each cell in that column until each cell has a total of 4 numbers. Essentially adding leading zeros.

Am I on the right track? What can I do to look up solutions or learn? I would like help writing this code but I also want to understand the thought process behind the decisions so I can continue my learning.

Comment: Ignoring any blank cells below the header?

Comment: Yes, we would want to ignore blank cells

Comment: Note: Don't use `Integer` for row counting variables. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Always use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Add_Leading_Zeros()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderRange As Range, HeaderCell As Range, c As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For Each HeaderCell In sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If LCase(HeaderCell) Like "*title*" Then
            For Each c In sht.Range(HeaderCell.Offset(1, 0), _
                                    sht.Cells(Rows.Count, HeaderCell.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                    c.NumberFormat = "@" 'Text
                    c.Value = Right("0000" & c.Value, 4)
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next HeaderCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow this part:
    c.NumberFormat = "@" 'Text
    c.Value = Right("0000" & c.Value, 4)

Would it be possible to explain what that means?

Comment: If you don't format a cell as Text before adding in a value like "0001" (for example) then Excel is likely to auto-convert it to just "1". Use of Right() is just to left-pad with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a leading zero to a cell:

```
cells(i,1).value = "0" & cells(i,1).value
```

The rest of your approach looks fine, in terms of what you're aiming to do... you've got quite a few issues with syntax, e.g., cells(1,columns.count) versus cells(rows.count,1).

I would say to be careful on the terms you're using to describe.  You are looking down a column and different rows, from what I can read in your code, but your post talks about finding items in a row.

If you are going down a column, you can use application.match to help determine if you have anything matching cells above your current cell, similar to:

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
With Sheets(1)
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If Application.Match(.Cells(i, 4), .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, 1)), 0) > lr Then .cells(i,1).value = "0" & .cells(i,1).value
    Next i
End With
```